# jQuery hide string in the URL if conains itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide the string that the url contains?

Let's say I have url: "example.com"

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("example") > -1) {
   window.location.href = "http://example.com/?t=440775";    
 }
```

this will get redirected and it add the number '?t=440775'

and now, how do I hide that number in the url?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?t=440775") > -1) {

 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to pass a variable to a different page to use, PHP would be your friend.

Comment: no, I just want to hide '?t=440775' in the domain. That's all.

Comment: If you don't want it to be visible to the users only then you have to do it through `.htaccess`

Comment: and how the permalinks work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You can't change the content of the adress-field of the browser, without redirecting to it.

Comment: I second that, it would cause serious security issues. (Mimicking online banking website and hiding the actual URL)

Comment: I don't want to hide the whole url, just that number

Comment: Yes. That means you will rewrite the URL in the adress bar, which is not possible. Use PHP to pass variables like this if you don't want them to show up in the adress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history Api to change url without reloading.

[history api](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?t=440775") > -1) {
     window.location.href = "http://example.com/";
}
```

:D

However, in all seriousness - you can't. For the server urls: `http://example.com/?t=440775` and `http://example.com/` are two totally different pages. If you want a specific action to commence, via JS, I'd suggest looking into `#` and [stateChange](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/).